# CLGeocoder returns inaccurate results

Tags: ios, objective-c, clgeocoder

I am using the method `geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString inRegion:(CLRegion *)region completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler` inside CLGeocoder and it returns bad coordinates for the address string Beverly Hills, CA. It does so only on the device. It works well on the simulator. The bad coordinates are still in the state of CA, but they are no where close to where Beverly Hills actually is. Any ideas? Here is my default search region:

`#define kDefaultSearchRegion [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.0, -100.0) radius:2758000.0 identifier:@"USA"]`

Here is my code:

```
- (void)onLocationSelected:(NSString *)location{
CLGeocoder *geocoderRequest;
__weak MTSRViewController *weakSelf = self;

  geocoderRequest = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

  //Show the loading view
    self.hud.taskInProgress = YES;
    [self.hud show:YES];

  [geocoderRequest geocodeAddressString:location
                               inRegion:kDefaultSearchRegion
                      completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              DLog(@"Geocoder fail %@",error);
                              [MTUtils alert:@"Unable to reach the internet. Please check your connection."];
                              weakSelf.hud.taskInProgress = NO;
                              [weakSelf.hud hide:YES];
                              return;
                          }

                          CLLocation *geocodedLocation;
                          NSString *formattedLocation;

                          geocodedLocation = [(CLPlacemark *)[placemarks lastObject] location];

                          formattedLocation = [weakSelf formattedStringFromCoordinate:[geocodedLocation coordinate]];

                          //Store for later
                          [weakSelf setPlacemark:[placemarks lastObject]];

                          [weakSelf updateSearchTags:@{
                                                       @"location": location,
                                                       @"where":formattedLocation
                                                       }];

                          [weakSelf reloadSearchResults];

                      }];

  //If there is an existing geocoder request, cancel it
  if ([[self geocoder] isGeocoding]) {
    [[self geocoder] cancelGeocode];
  }

  //Retain a reference so we can cancel the request
  [self setGeocoder:geocoderRequest];
}
```

The lat/lng I get are for some area in Northern California, which is close to where I am.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: What latitude and longitude you're getting?

Comment: geocoding a random address isn't guaranteed to be accurate. The simulator and the device might use different endpoints... but that you get different results is weird. .. **what kind of devices are involved?**

Comment: show us formattedStringFromCoordinate